# Inserting value in Key Words field of EA programmatically

Tags: enterprise-architect

I am trying to insert a value in 'Key Words' field of Enterprise Architect 11.1.1112 programmatically. My code is:

case "Key Words": _elm.Tag = Convert.ToString(edtl.FieldValue);
                  break;

[Here _elm is a object of EA.Element class]
Although there is a value in edtl.Fieldvalue variable, the value is not getting shown in EA.
I found from Sparx Syatem's site that Tag corresponds to Key Words field in EA and that the field is not a readonly field.

Answer (score 1):

I guess your Convert fails. Try to assign a string directly. I ran this piece of Perl code with no issue:

```
my $e = $rep->GetTreeSelectedObject();
$e->{Tag} = "Hello";
$e->Update();
```

Comment: Thomas, it was a fault from my end. I forgot to uninstall the old addin from my machine. Due to some reasons the old addin was running in my system which does not had the code written to insert value in that field. Now its working. Thanks by the way for your help.